# How to write the expect script to install mariadb?

Tags: automation, centos, mariadb, expect, tcltk

Environment: centos7 + mariadb5.5.64.
Let me show the installation info on screen when to run `mysql_secure_installation`.

```
# mysql_secure_installation

NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MariaDB
      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!

In order to log into MariaDB to secure it, we'll need the current
password for the root user.  If you've just installed MariaDB, and
you haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank,
so you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
OK, successfully used password, moving on...

Setting the root password ensures that nobody can log into the MariaDB
root user without the proper authorisation.

Set root password? [Y/n] y
New password: 
Re-enter new password: 
Password updated successfully!
Reloading privilege tables..
 ... Success!


By default, a MariaDB installation has an anonymous user, allowing anyone
to log into MariaDB without having to have a user account created for
them.  This is intended only for testing, and to make the installation
go a bit smoother.  You should remove them before moving into a
production environment.

Remove anonymous users? [Y/n] y
 ... Success!

Normally, root should only be allowed to connect from 'localhost'.  This
ensures that someone cannot guess at the root password from the network.

Disallow root login remotely? [Y/n] y
 ... Success!

By default, MariaDB comes with a database named 'test' that anyone can
access.  This is also intended only for testing, and should be removed
before moving into a production environment.

Remove test database and access to it? [Y/n] y
 - Dropping test database...
 ... Success!
 - Removing privileges on test database...
 ... Success!

Reloading the privilege tables will ensure that all changes made so far
will take effect immediately.

Reload privilege tables now? [Y/n] y
 ... Success!

Cleaning up...

All done!  If you've completed all of the above steps, your MariaDB
installation should now be secure.

Thanks for using MariaDB!
```

I write an automation expect script to install mariadb.

```
  vim secure.exp
  set timeout 60
  spawn mysql_secure_installation
  expect {
      "Enter current password for root (enter for none): " {send "\r";exp_continue}
      "Set root password? [Y/n] " {send "y\r";exp_continue}
      "New password:" {send "123456\r";exp_continue}
      "Re-enter new password:" {send "123456\r";exp_continue}
      "Remove anonymous users? [Y/n]" {send "y\r";exp_continue}
      "Disallow root login remotely? [Y/n]" {send "y\r";exp_continue}
      "Remove test database and access to it? [Y/n]" {send "y\r";exp_continue}
      "Reload privilege tables now? [Y/n]" {send "y\r";exp_continue}
  }
```

To execute `/usr/bin/expect secure.exp`, i come across the error:

```
spawn mysql_secure_installation
invalid command name "Y/n"
    while executing
"Y/n"
    invoked from within
"expect {
          "Enter current password for root (enter for none): " {send "\r";exp_continue}
          "Set root password? [Y/n] " {send "y\r";exp..."
    (file "secure.exp" line 3)
```

It is no use to write as below:

```
  set timeout 60
  spawn mysql_secure_installation
  expect {
      "Enter current password for root (enter for none): " {send "\r";exp_continue}
      "Set root password? \\[Y/n] " {send "y\r";exp_continue}
      "New password:" {send "123456\r";exp_continue}
      "Re-enter new password:" {send "123456\r";exp_continue}
      "Remove anonymous users? \\[Y/n]" {send "y\r";exp_continue}
      "Disallow root login remotely? \\[Y/n]" {send "y\r";exp_continue}
      "Remove test database and access to it? \\[Y/n]" {send "y\r";exp_continue}
      "Reload privilege tables now? \\[Y/n]" {send "y\r";exp_continue}
  }
```

Same error:

```
invalid command name "Y/n"
    while executing
"Y/n"
    invoked from within
"expect {
      "Enter current password for root (enter for none): " {send "\r";exp_continue}
      "Set root password? \\[Y/n] " {send "y\r";exp_conti..."
    (file "secure.exp" line 3)
```

How to fix my exp script then?

Comment: Expect is a Tcl extension. In Tcl, `[ ... ]` is *command substitution* which is like shell's `$( ... )`. So `"Set root password? [Y/n] "` should be written as `"Set root password? \\[Y/n] "`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These scripts wait to receive optional output (`timeout -1` means "no timeout") and they can tell apart different responses, as it is required by `yum install` and  `mysql_secure_installation`. With `#!/bin/expect -f` as shebang, the scripts can be executed, when they were set to `chmod +x`.

A) To begin with, `mariadb_yum.exp` (requires `su` or `sudo`):

```
#!/bin/expect -f
set timeout 30
if {[llength $argv] == 0} {
    send_user "Usage: mariadb_yum.exp \[linux sudo password\]\n"
    exit 1
}
set USERNAME "[exec whoami]"
set PASSWORD [lindex $argv 0];

# optionally, redirect output to log file (silent install)
# log_user 0
# log_file -a "/home/$USERNAME/mariadb_install.log"

spawn sudo yum -y install MariaDB-server
set yum_spawn_id $spawn_id

# On GCE it will never ask for a sudo password:
expect -ex "\[sudo\] password for $USERNAME: " {
   exp_send "$PASSWORD\r"
}

expect {
    # when the package was already installed
    -ex "Nothing to do" {
        send_user "package was already installed\n"
    }
    # when the package had been installed
    -ex "Complete!" {
        send_user "package had been installed\n"
    }
}

expect eof
close $yum_spawn_id
exit 0
```

B) And then `mariadb_sec.exp` (doesn't require `sudo`):

```
#!/bin/expect -f
set timeout 1
if {[llength $argv] == 0} {
    send_user "Usage: mariadb_sec.exp \[mysql root password\]\n"
    exit 1
}
set PASSWORD [lindex $argv 0];

spawn mysql_secure_installation
set mysql_spawn_id $spawn_id

# optionally, redirect output to log file (silent install)
# log_user 0
# log_file -a "/home/[exec whoami]/mariadb_install.log"

# when there is no password set, this probably should be "\r"
expect -ex "Enter current password for root (enter for none): "
exp_send "$PASSWORD\r"

expect {
    # await an eventual error message
    -ex "ERROR 1045" {
        send_user "\nMariaDB > An invalid root password had been provided.\n"
        close $mysql_spawn_id
        exit 1
    }
    # when there is a root password set
    -ex "Change the root password? \[Y/n\] " {
        exp_send "n\r"
    }
    # when there is no root password set (could not test this branch).
    -ex "Set root password? \[Y/n\] " {
        exp_send "Y\r"
        expect -ex "New password: "
        exp_send "$PASSWORD\r"
        expect -ex "Re-enter new password: "
        exp_send "$PASSWORD\r"
    }
}
expect -ex "Remove anonymous users? \[Y/n\] "
exp_send "Y\r"
expect -ex "Disallow root login remotely? \[Y/n\] "
exp_send "Y\r"
expect -ex "Remove test database and access to it? \[Y/n\] "
exp_send "Y\r"
expect -ex "Reload privilege tables now? \[Y/n\] "
exp_send "Y\r"

expect eof
close $mysql_spawn_id
exit 0
```

---

For debugging purposes - or to validate the answer, one can run `expect` with log-level `strace 4`. This is probably as reputable as a source can get, when it comes to writing `expect` scripts, as it nicely displays what is going on and most importantly, in which order the things happen:

```
expect -c "strace 4" ./mariadb_yum.exp [linux sudo password]
expect -c "strace 4" ./mariadb_sec.exp [mysql root password]
```

Instruction `set exp_internal 1` can be used to get output for the regex-matching.

---

A possible source of confusion might be, where one spawns the processes - as one can spawn several process on various hosts, eg. `ssh` locally and then `yum` and `mysql_secure_installation` remotely. Added `$spawn_id` to the script; the bottom one `close` call might be redundant, since it is already `EOF` (just to show how to `spawn` & `close` processes):

```
Thanks for using MariaDB!
 1  close $mysql_spawn_id
 1  exit 0
 2  rename _close.pre_expect close
```

---

Conclusion: The `mariadb_sec.exp` script probably could be improved further, eg. when at first sending no password and seeing what happens - then sending the password on `ERROR 1045` (when a password had already been set previously). It may be save to assume, that one has to set the password when the server just has been installed (except that `yum reinstall` delivers the same result). Just had no blank CentOS container to test all the cases. Unless running in a `root` shell, passing both kinds of passwords into one script would be required to automate this from installation until post-installation.

Probably worth noting is that on GCE, `sudo` would not ask for a password; there are indeed minor differences based upon the environment, as these CentOS container images behave differently. In such case (since there is no `su` or container-image detection in place), the `mariadb_yum.exp` script might get stuck for `30` seconds and then continue.

---

The most reputable sources I can offer are the [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) manual, written by Don Libes @ NIST  and the TCL/TK manual for [`expect`](https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index), along with it's SourceForge project coincidentally called [`expect`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/expect/).

Answer (score 2):

Not only are square brackets used for command substitution, but [they are also special for glob patterns](https://superuser.com/a/1278754/778853).

You can either use the `-exact` switch while escaping the square brackets in quotes:

```
spawn mysql_secure_installation
expect {
    ...
    -exact "Set root password? \[Y/n\] " {send "y\r";exp_continue}
    ...
}
```

Or use braces instead of quotes:

```
spawn mysql_secure_installation
expect {
    ...
    {Set root password? \[Y/n\] } {send "y\r";exp_continue}
    ...
}
```

FYI you can have the expect script generated for you by using `autoexpect`:

```
autoexpect ./mysql_secure_installation
```

This will generate an expect script called `script.exp` in your present working directory.